# strange processes on Windows

Tags: windows, boot, process, task-manager

can somebody explain how can I delete unnecessary processes on windows? For example I deleted icq, but I still have some icq processes on Windows Task Manager.
Every time when I start my windows I have a lot of unnecessary processes.

Thanks in advance (I have windows xp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use system configuration to remove entries from your startup lists;

- Start, run, "msconfig".
- Go to the "Startup" tab and uncheck things you no longer use or do not recognise.

You may also want to go through your startup services and set some of them to "Manual" or "Disabled".

- Start, run, "services.msc"
- See [this guide](http://www.theeldergeek.com/services_guide.htm) for information on which services you can safely disable.

Comment: +1 for remembering to mention services, I forgot about that.